Corrupted font on whatsdesk and trello-desktop
A couple of days ago, I had some issues with my fonts, my i3wm lost its icons and had to change the font (okay), however after installing trello-desktop, I noticed some blank rectangles in place of text characters errors, that have also manifested in whatsdesk:

I know I have to modify the fonts, but I believe it has to do with dependencies. It most likely affects other apps, but these are the one I have seen it on.
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic


You've not provided base Ubuntu product & release details; why make us guess. I have seen that appear when a config file tells it to use a font that doesn't exist, or is unsuitable for how it was used; so I'd suggest checking your configs.  there are other reasons too, but I don't know what exactly you're running so won't speculate further

@guiverc I have i3wm, and added an edit. Do you mean config files such as .bashrc or config (i3wm)? .bashrc doesn't have a "font" coincidence, and config (i3wm) has my font config, which is working as expected.

Seems similar to this question about Ubuntu 18.04, in particular the way your snap installation is configured. I've also got the same issues, and haven't solved the problem yet.
